# Need to include pipeline job inside jenkins "build metrics" plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-plugins

I am using "Build Metrics" plugin in jenkins. It is showing free style jobs details only not including pipeline jobs.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/53te9.png)

I need to include pipeline job inside this plugin or do you know any other plugin to get pipeline report.

Comment: How did you configure the plugin? Can you show the SS of that?

Comment: @Hardik Rathod I used this https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-metrics/ link to configure.

Comment: @HardikRathod actually i have to generate report for jenkins jobs like Total Builds for each project,Failures,Success,Average time per build for each job. If you know any other plugin for this. Please let me know.

Comment: My initial feeling is that this plugin is not able to consider pipeline jobs in it. I tried by providing the regex in job filtering.

Comment: @HardikRathod Thanks for your continues reply. Yes i also tried.

Comment: @HardikRathod Do you know any other plugin to generate reports?

Comment: not in my knowledge. I think this is a good chance for a contribution. :)
I am checking the original plugin code to see if I can contribute anything here.

Comment: There is a reason why this plugin does not show results for pipeline jobs. I checked the code and it uses build metrics plugin to get the results of jobs. Now build metrics plugin itself does not have support for pipeline jobs. That is the reason why this is not working. 

So only way to make it work with this plugin is that, we need to modify the code of either build metrics/build stats. Or you can use the plugin @Ozzy suggested.

Comment: Also, modification of either of the plugin is not that straight forward. In order to consider pipeline jobs, one has to include the dependency on workflow job plugin. Which results into installation of 48 other plugins. So you could just go ahead and make it work for your environment but I am not sure if open source community will go for this change.

Comment: Checkout this: [Results](https://imgur.com/a/rUp9NEe)

There is a minor issue though. It is showing pipeline builds according to their build number which should not happen. I am planning to solve it tomorrow. It's very late here right now.

Comment: I did not get a chance to work on it again. Will get back once I have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the Jenkins configuration page for the Build Metrics plugin.

2.Scroll down to the "Job Type Filter" section and select the "Pipeline" option.

3.Save the changes and restart Jenkins.

4.Go back to the Build Metrics dashboard and you should now see the pipeline jobs included in the report.

Alternatively, you can use the Jenkins Performance Plugin to get a report on pipeline jobs. This plugin provides detailed performance reports for both freestyle and pipeline jobs, and it also includes graphs and charts to help you visualize the performance data. You can find more information and installation instructions for the Jenkins Performance Plugin on the official Jenkins website.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked "Job Type Filter" section but it is not there. @Ozzy Can you share screenshot for that? If you share really helpful to me.

Comment: @Ozzy where are you referring to? I checked manage jenkins -> configure system, global tool configuration, build metrics. Not able to find the option you are pointing to.